# How to purge items from Dash Menu

Tags: unity, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove icons/shortcuts from Unity menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71240/how-to-remove-icons-shortcuts-from-unity-menu)

I've just failed at installing iTunes in WINE - it looked absolutely horrible. Since I've removed it using PlayOnLinux, it's still showing up in the start menu (when I press my Windows Key, the full screen that comes up full of apps).

How do I purge this from this screen? I'm tired of looking at broken shortcuts and stuff that sits there and doesn't work. Is there a file or something I can go in and fool around with?

Comment: You can find an answer to your question in this other question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/71240/how-to-remove-icons-shortcuts-from-unity-menu/71245#71245