# Unity search, how to get rid of certain results?

Tags: unity, launcher, zeitgeist

When i want to run the *calculator*, i click on unity first icon (dashboard?), and then i start to type :

*ca* : is showing the *calculator* as first result (probably because zeitgeist recorded that its the app i use the most)
*cal* : is still showing the *calculator* as first result
*calc* : is showing *libreoffice calc* as first result

It's annoying because if i hit "enter" *libreoffice calc* is launched :(

I tried to blacklist *libreoffice calc* in "activity log manager" but the behavior didn't change.
So the main question is :
**How to prevent *libreoffice calc* to show up as first result without removing it completely from unity ?**
And to go further :
**Why is it showing up as first result on search with "*calc*" and not with "*cal*" or "*ca*" ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is it showing up as first result on search with "calc" and not with "cal" or "ca"?

That is because until you write `calc` it is sorting alphabetically, when you write `calc` there will be a program that contains the full word (*LibreOffice Calc*) so that program will jump to the first position on the list, its called a hit.

We can then assume that the dash search will look first for possible matches and sort them alphabetically if none matches the complete query and display hits always on the first positions if it found a matching word.

> How to prevent LibreOffice Calc to show up as first result without removing it completely from Unity?

Has for the first part of your question you should look at

- [How to remove icons/shortcuts from Unity menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71240/how-to-remove-icons-shortcuts-from-unity-menu)

it explains how and why you cannot simply remove a search result (with a possible workaround for it).

There is no way to just hide one single application without removing the global shortcut for it (even tough you could still have that shortcut on the Desktop for example).

Comment: ok, so it has nothing to do with "most used" app if as you said, for "ca" or "cal", it's sorted alphabetically ? renaming "openoffice calc" to "openoffice:calc" may do the trick ? (as long as ':' is not considered as an ifs), no way to configure the search engine to consider names containing spaces as a single string ?

Comment: this solution stands for Synapse search/launcher that can be used in other DE than Unity. just remove desktop files from usr/share/applications. see this http://askubuntu.com/q/233973/47206