# How do I delete an icon from dash?

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove icons/shortcuts from Unity menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71240/how-to-remove-icons-shortcuts-from-unity-menu)

I installed Adobe Reader on Ubuntu 12.04 from a .bin file, but it was not working properly so I want to remove it and reinstall it using Ubuntu Software Center. To remove it I deleted its source file, but I was not able to delete its icon from the dash home.

Can anyone please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Like jokerdino has mentioned. Right click on that icon and choose `Unlock from Launcher`.