# How to remove individual webapps from Launcher

Tags: launcher, webapps

Today my launcher looks like a long vertical bar of icons. I have 14 webapp icons on the launcher but there is no option to remove them or an option to no include them (Or even an option to merge them as I asked in a previous question). Is there an option, without having to disable the whole webapp idea, to remove individual webapps from the launcher.

Forgot to add that the option to Unlock from Launcher does not appear, but only on the webapps. On the rest of the launcher icons it appears correctly.

This is an image of the actual problem (Thanks to koma):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this is a bug.  I've filed a [bug report about it here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-firefox-extension/+bug/1033397).

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the application and select "Unlock from Launcher":

[image]

Though the application itself will still remain in the application lens in the Unity  dash, to remove an application from there follow these instructions:

- [How to remove icons/shortcuts from Unity menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71240/how-to-remove-icons-shortcuts-from-unity-menu)

Comment: Hi Jorge, well the option to Unlock does not appear. Forgot that tiny detail in the question.

Comment: It's supposed to have one, probably file a bug report on lp:webapps. I'll generalize this question since it's supposed to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Pandora and fixed it the following way:

1. Lock the webapp to the launcher.
2. Close all instances of the webapp.
3. Use the webapp icon in the launcher to load the webapp.
4. Close the webapp.
5. Unlock the webapp from the launcher and it will not reappear on launcher next time you visit the site.

However, this does not stop the webapp from appearing in the dash. Also right clicking the Pandora webapp in the dash does not give me the option to uninstall like with the built in Amazon webapp despite Pandora being supported.

This does appear to be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

The above two solutions do not work.

As mentioned above there is no option to 'unlock from launcher', unless you have previously locked the icon to the launcher.

As i understand it, locking to the launcher means that the icon will show up regardless of whether the webpage is open or not. If it is unlocked it will disappear when the webpage is closed and reappear when it is opened.

However to remove the icon from the launcher, so that it does not appear regardless of whether you visit the webpage you have to uninstall the relevant webapp from the software centre.

1. Open software centre
2. search for the specific web app eg."unity-webapps-gmail" or "unity-webapps-googledocs"
3. Click uninstall

Answer is here:http://askubuntu.com/questions/166655/how-do-i-remove-a-website-from-ubuntus-web-applications?rq=1

Comment: +1 because, yeah, that would actually solve the problem. I will still leave it in the bug report since it was a bug at the time of asking the question. Thanks MorrisseyJ.