# Remove dead link in Unity dock

Tags: unity, launcher, dock

I had libre office calc locked to my launcher dock but when I removed libre office the icon stayed on the dock and now I cannot remove it. Right clicking on it gives me the option "unlock from launcher" but when I do that it is still there.

According to "[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71240/how-to-remove-icons-shortcuts-from-unity-menu)" I tried to look for the .desktop file but cannot find one for libre office anywhere.

Suggestions as to how to remove it?

Comment: Which versions? Did you install LibreOffice manually or from the archives? Details, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal and enter:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
```

The command would output the items currently in the launcher like this:

```
['ubiquity-gtkui.desktop', 'nautilus-home.desktop', 'libreoffice-calc.desktop', 'gnome-control-center.desktop']
```

Now if you want to remove `libreoffice-calc`, exclude it's `.desktop` entry and set the new favourite string as:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['ubiquity-gtkui.desktop', 'nautilus-home.desktop', 'gnome-control-center.desktop']"
```

*(take care of the separators and quotes.)*

To delete the `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` use:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-calc.desktop
```