# How do I remove invalid shortcuts?

Tags: shortcuts

How do I remove invalid (orphaned) shortcuts from Ubuntu 14.04? I have Wine, PlayOnLinux and ClassicMenu Indicator installed. I installed, then removed Microsoft Office 2007 because it was "buggy". However, their shortcuts remain in the "Other" subfolder of ClassicMenu Indicator. Suggesions, please.

Answer (score 3):

Try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/71245/121372):

> It seems that you can't remove apps from the Dash, however you can
>   manage your launchers (*.desktop files) in one of the following
>   directories:
>
> - /usr/share/applications
> - /usr/local/share/applications
> - ~/.local/share/applications
>
> If your launcher file is in any of the first two directories, you will
>   require root permissions to remove it.

Comment: if the app is still there , but for some reason the path changed ( Battle.net in my case ) you can create a new shortcut in PoL and open the shortcut ( in Ubuntu *.desktop ) in a text editor and change the --run argument in the Exec setting