# How to remove uninstalled wine app icons from unity dash?

Tags: 12.10, wine, uninstall, unity-dash

I installed [**LAN Messenger**](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http://lanmsngr.sourceforge.net/&ei=K5-eU6nJINicugSHloGoDA&usg=AFQjCNE8b3yGnl-ktaViEd19QEIiQUfI_g&bvm=bv.68911936,d.c2E) (for Windows) using wine but turns out LAN Messenger is also available for linux as well. So..

- I uninstalled LAN Messenger from wine.
- I also removed wine.
- deleted the `.wine` directory.
- after that `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get autoclean`.
- then I installed LAN Messenger using `dpkg -i pkgname.deb` and it installed successfully.

**The problem is** that now I get this in dash:
[image: Dash]

Any Help is highly appreciated.

**[NOTE] I am using ubuntu 12.10**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I fixed it:

- open terminal and `cd ~/.local/share/applications`.
- `ls -a` and there were few `wine-***` files and a folder `wine`.[image]
- now you can do a selective remove or; in my case; delete all those files using `rm -rf wine*`

Problem solved!

curtsy: https://askubuntu.com/a/71245/241969

Comment: You don't have to delete everything as you may lose other useful icons too. Inside  ~/.local/share/applications/wine/programs there are folders regarding each one of your wine apps. Delete the unwanted ones and keep the rest.

Comment: @John Thanks for pointing that out. Updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome, if you want to remove all the icons which we have instaled using wine, this is the technique to follow...Thanks, man.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bunch of old applications/games that I could not remove. In my case `~/.local/share/applications` also contained folders and subfolders!

```
~/.local/share/applications$ tree
.
├── gog_com-Streets_of_Rage_4_1.desktop
├── mimeapps.list
├── mimeinfo.cache
├── vlc_1_5.desktop
├── vlc_2_0.desktop
├── wine
│   └── Programs
│       ├── Diablo [GOG.com]
│       │   ├── Diablo.desktop
│       │   ├── Documents
│       │   │   └── Manual.desktop
│       │   └── Uninstall Diablo.desktop
│       ├── Sacred Gold [GOG.com]
│       │   ├── Dedicated Game Server.desktop
│       │   ├── Documents
│       │   │   ├── Map.desktop
│       │   │   ├── Quickstart.desktop
│       │   │   ├── Readme.desktop
│       │   │   └── Руководство.desktop
│       │   ├── Sacred Gold.desktop
│       │   ├── Settings.desktop
│       │   └── Uninstall Sacred Gold.desktop
│       └── SADPTool
│           ├── SADPTool.desktop
│           └── Uninstall SADPTool.desktop
├── wine-extension-chm.desktop
├── wine-extension-hlp.desktop
├── wine-extension-msp.desktop
└── wine-extension-vbs.desktop
```

So I had to remove `*.desktop` files in subfolders also.