# Can't start gvim from the launcher

Tags: launcher, vim

I don't know why I've been having so many problems with gvim lately, but now I can't start it from the launcher.  I click on it, and it glows and pulsates for awhile, but after a few seconds it stops pulsating and nothing happens.

I created the launcher icon by opening gvim, right-clicking on it and clicking "Lock to Launcher".  I've tried opening it through nautilus with the right-click context menu, and I've tried running it through the terminal.  Both times I would right-click on the icon and click "Lock to Launcher".  Both methods have the same result.

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same problem, and solved it by the steps below.

1. `rm ~/.local/share/applications/gvim.desktop`
2. type `gvim` in terminal and lock 'gvim' to ubuntu dash again.
3. Actually, you can modify 'path' in '~/.local/share/applications/gvim.desktop' file to your home directory, because this is the original source that this problem came from.

reference:
[How to remove icons/shortcuts from Unity menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71240/how-to-remove-icons-shortcuts-from-unity-menu)

Answer (score 0):

Vim opens in Terminal

Crl-Alt-T

from command line

vim

If you have installed gvim, the gui for vim, you should be able to locate it in the dash, and lock to your launcher.

If you are unable to open vim from Terminal, try this

```
sudo apt-get remove vim-gnome
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

To start from the command line

```
gvim <file-name-to-open>
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant gvim.  I have it locked to the launcher, but clicking on it doesn't open the program.

Comment: How did you install gvim, software center?

Comment: See edit answer to remove gvim then re-install.

Comment: I uninstalled vim-gnome and installed vim-gtk to solve another problem, but it still doesn't open from the launcher.  The launcher icon just blinks for a little while.  I wonder if there's some kind of log file that would tell me what's happening?

Comment: Yes, /var/log/dmesg.  Try running "cat /var/log/dmesg | grep gvim" then run it again replacing gvim with vim-gnome.