# Move and remove icons in the Unity Dock

Tags: unity, ubuntu-dock, dock, gsettings

Is there an easy way to add or remove icons in the Unity Dock from the command line?

I would have expected something like `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions...`, but most solutions require Python programming. Is there a clean Bash way of doing things?

Answer (score 0):

I found this, it is a bit outdated, but it should still help you:

[How to remove icons/shortcuts from Unity menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71240/how-to-remove-icons-shortcuts-from-unity-menu)