# Eclipse appears in application drawer without icon after removal

Tags: eclipse

After I did:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse
sudo apt-get purge eclipse
```

and deleted some folders like `.eclipse` and `./eclipse-installer` in `/home/user/` but there is a blank space with the Eclipse apps name

[image: Show Application screen]

How can I fix that? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Output of `grep -R "Eclipse" /usr/share/applications ~/.local/share/applications`:

```
/home/user/.local/share/applications/epp.package.java.desktop:Name=Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - 2021-03
/home/user/.local/share/applications/epp.package.java.desktop:Categories=Eclipse
/home/user/.local/share/applications/epp.package.cpp.desktop.1616310086817.backup:Name=Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers - 2021-03
/home/user/.local/share/applications/epp.package.cpp.desktop.1616310086817.backup:Categories=Eclipse
/home/user/.local/share/applications/epp.package.cpp.desktop:Name=Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers - 2021-03
/home/user/.local/share/applications/epp.package.cpp.desktop:Categories=Eclipse
/home/user/.local/share/applications/epp.package.java.desktop.1616310029426.backup:Name=Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - 2020-12
/home/user/.local/share/applications/epp.package.java.desktop.1616310029426.backup:Categories=Eclipse
```

Comment: Are you sure you installed Eclipse using APT, not with some tar downloaded from Eclipse's site? Please [edit] your question and paste the output of `grep -R "Eclipse" /usr/share/applications ~/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli yes, i did

Comment: There you go. Run `rm ~/.local/share/applications/epp.package*`. If entries in application drawer still appear, press Alt+F2, type `r` and press Enter.

Comment: @Kulfy So many thanks dude, u saved me, they disappeared

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove icons/shortcuts from Unity menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71240/how-to-remove-icons-shortcuts-from-unity-menu) Though you're not using Unity, some things are still same.