# Purge Clipit on Ubuntu 20.04 not working

Tags: 20.04, software-center, uninstall, clipboard, purge

I installed clipit by following the instructions on this page for Ubuntu (https://github.com/CristianHenzel/ClipIt#on-ubuntu) so I used the command `sudo apt-get install build-essential git automake xdotool autoconf intltool autopoint gtk+-3.0` and then

```
tar zxvf clipit-x.y.z.tar.gz
cd clipit-x.y.z
./autogen.sh
./configure --with-gtk3 
make
sudo make install
```

It was not showing up on the dash and I was not able to perform any modifications on its settings through preferences or any other options. So, I uninstalled it with `sudo apt-get purge clipit` and then `sudo apt-get autoremove`
I also tried remove command but it seems nothing worked and it still is usable and being shown when I search for it.

I also tried to remove it from ubuntu software but it didn't show remove but showed the button to install. I tried the command `dpkg --list` to see if clipit was there before starting any procedure for uninstalling but it didn't show there before and after.
H

How can I uninstall clipit completely without any trace?

> Edit: This answer helped me solve this problem:
> https://askubuntu.com/a/71245/1416525
>
> It seems that you can't remove apps from the Dash, however you can manage your launchers (*.desktop files) in one of the following directories:
> `/usr/share/applications`
> `/usr/local/share/applications`
> `~/.local/share/applications`
> If your launcher file is in any of the first two directories, you will require root permissions to remove it.

Comment: You built clipit from source, you didn't install it with apt, so you shouldn't expect that removing it with apt would work.

Comment: Try `sudo make uninstall`. If you installed via `Makefile`, you have to uninstall it via `Makefike`.

Comment: What was wrong with https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/clipit ? Why do you make Ubuntu to act like Gentoo or LFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case uninstall via apt will not work. You need to remove clipit from `/usr` as while installation it default get installed there.
You can find all `clipit` files and remove it by below command.

```
sudo find / -name "clipit" -delete
```

Comment: This seems to work though this is also the same I think: https://askubuntu.com/a/71245/1416525

Answer (score 1):

Apt is not magical. Apt can only uninstall deb packages. Not Snaps, not Flatpaks, not Pip Wheels, not *software compiled from source* (that's what you did), not anything else.

So apt can uninstall `build-essential git automake xdotool autoconf intltool autopoint gtk+-3.0` -- those are the prerequisites that you installed.

But apt cannot undo a `make install`. That's not a deb package.

- Review your install instructions. Perhaps there were uninstall instructions.
- Review the makefile. Maybe there is a `make uninstall` defined. Alternately, folks who are skilled at reading the makefile (not too difficult, try it!) can figure out which files were installed and manually delete those files.
- If there are no uninstall instructions at all, anywhere (including the upstream GitHub source), then open an issue on GitHub: Ask the author for uninstall instructions or a makefile uninstall.
- Reminder: If you really care about the software, and the license is compatible, you can package the software as a Deb or Snap. With a compatible license, you don't need anybody's permission. Then the software CAN be removed by existing package tools, and the entire community can benefit from the software.

Comment: Yes, it's almost always `sudo make uninstall`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only used apt to install it then
`sudo apt-get purge clipit*`
note the asterix

Comment: The author of the question installed clipit from source.